# SDE solver in python: manual determination of integrator step size (dt)

Tags: python, ode, stochastic-ode

**Aim**: I am trying to solve a system of SDEs, while using the `SDEint` package in python 3.x. It is a system of SDEs adapted from and inspired by the Zombie Apocalypse model, published by [Munz, 2009](https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rsmith43/Zombies.pdf). I tried to add an explanation of the terms within the code.

**Problem**: The problem I would like to solve occurs in the example below (overflow encoutered in double_scalar). Note that the noice term is currently 0, so it is basically a system of ODEs and not yet a system of SDEs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sdeint
from scipy.integrate import odeint

p, f, e, k = 0.7, 0.0002, 0.05, 0.02    # human birth rate, confilt occurence rate, conflict end rate, zombie killing rate

tspan = np.linspace(0, 20., 100)
y0 = np.array([100000., 0., 0., p])

def ff(y, t):
    Hi = y[0]
    Ci = y[1]
    Zi = y[2]

    # Human are created (exponential)                       --> y[3] * Hi
    # Humans and zombies engage in conflict at rate (f)     --> - f * Hi * Zi
    # the conficts end at rate (e) without a victor         --> + e * Ci
    f0 = y[3] * Hi - f * Hi * Zi + e * Ci

    # Humans and zombies engage in conflict at rate (f)     --> f * Hi * Zi
    # the conficts end at rate (e) without a victor         --> - e * Ci
    # and zombies kill humans in conflict at rate (k)       --> - k * Ci
    f1 = f * Hi * Zi - e * Ci - k * Ci

    # Zombies arise from the earth at a fixed rate          --> 10**7
    # they arise as victor from a conflict                  --> + k * Ci
    # enter conflicts                                       --> - f * Hi * Zi
    # and exit conflicts without killing                    --> + e * Ci
    f2 = 10**7 + k * Ci - f * Hi * Zi + e * Ci

    f3 = 0
    print(f0, f1 ,f2, f3)
    return np.array([f0, f1, f2, f3])

def GG(y, t):
    return np.diag([0, 0, 0, 0])

result = sdeint.itoint(ff, GG, y0, tspan)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(bottom=1, top=10**13)
plt.plot(result)
plt.show()
```

I have tried to solve the same system of ODEs (without noise) using Scipy's `odeint` and this seems to work well due to the possibility of adding several arguments to `odeint`.

```
result = odeint(ff, y0, tspan, mxstep=10 ** 9, rtol=10 ** (-3),
                atol=10 ** (-3), hmax=1)
```

So I thought maybe `SDEint` uses too large integration steps, however there is no possibility to manually add additional arguments to `sdeint`.

**Potential Solution(?)**: So I was wondering, if a solution might be to manually set the set size of the integration. I tried to do so by increasing the amount of steps in `np.linspace` e.g.

```
tspan = np.linspace(0, 20., 100000) # 100 --> 100000
```

However, this does not seem to work properly.

**Question**: Since I am not really familiar with ODEs/SDEs, I am not sure if I am addressing this problem properly. Is this a common way to address the problem of too large integration steps? And might the solution be to increase the step size or am I completely mistaken?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add your reasoning for the parameter choice? You add to a variable with initial value 0.0001 that is constant in the original version a noise of variance 1e4*dt. With such a perturbation I could imagine that any non-linear model rapidly finds a region of positive feed-back and then divergence.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I tried to come up with a reproducible example, however maybe it was not the best... The main problem is that I translated an ODE system into SDEs. `odeint` was able to integrate perfectly (small step size, args atol/rtol 10^-3), however the same system (even without noise term) explodes in SDEint. I thought that a manually fixed step size might solve the problem, however I am not completely sure.

Comment: I tried to come up with an improved reproducible example of the problem I am facing. Hopefully I have succeeded:) In short: I am able to solve an ODE system and I would like to make it into an SDE system, so I used the package SDEint. Without the ability to add arguments to `sdeint` the system crashed, I think due to a larger integration step size.

Comment: SDEint without noise should reduce to the Heun or explicit trapezoidal method, a second order method. It is possible that variables become accidentially negative due to the larger step errors and then enter a positive feed-back cycle exploding the system.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent these accidental negative variables or larger step errors?

Comment: You could parametrize $x=\exp(u)$, $y=\exp(v)$. If the SDE formulation translates to $(u,v)$ space without introducing singularities (or you only add the noise terms in $(u,v)$ space), you get always positive solutions in $(x,y)$ space.